# How to add a text in existing .docx file on desired location

Tags: vb.net, ms-word

I want to open an existing .docx file and insert some text in second paragraph.

```
Private Sub insertText()
Dim WordApp As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application
Dim aDoc As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document = WordApp.Documents.Open("C:\File1.docx")
Dim RNG As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range()

end sub
```

Now what should I write to insert some text in second para ??
Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Application.Selection.TypeText()` for that:

```
 Private Sub insertText()
    Dim WordApp As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application
    WordApp.Visible = True
    Dim aDoc As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document = WordApp.Documents.Open("C:\File1.docx")

    Dim paragraphs As Word.Paragraphs = aDoc.Paragraphs

    If (paragraphs.Count > 1) Then
        paragraphs(2).Range.Select()
        WordApp.Selection.TypeText("test")
    End If

    aDoc.Save()
    aDoc.Close()

    WordApp.Quit()
End Sub
```

You should probably close up the document then word safely so you don't have a winword.exe hanging after your program is finished ( I added this quick-and-dirty for you, but its not 100% foolproof)

Please excuse my poor, lazy vb.net style. If you like c sharp - note that c sharp since v4.0 is MUCH better than it used to be with Office Interop, and I recommend it.

Comment: @Jack. Thanks a lot for giving attention. God Bless You

Comment: @Jack, Error in paragraphs.Count. Count is not the member of Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Paragraph. What should i do here ??

Comment: @Jack, Error in paragraphs.Count. Count is not the member of Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Paragraph. What should i do here ?? And also what if there is something written in second para ?? Code should insert a new para above existing second para and then text should be inserted in this newly created para..

Answer (score 0):

Yes.. I got the answer..

```
Private Sub insertText()
    Dim WordApp As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application
    Dim aDoc As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document = WordApp.Documents.Open("C:\File1.docx")
    Dim RNG As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range()
    Dim PARA As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Paragraph = aDoc.Paragraphs.Add()

    If aDoc.Paragraphs.Count > 1 Then
        aDoc.Paragraphs(2).Range.InsertParagraphBefore()
        aDoc.Paragraphs(2).Range.Text = "Hello World"
    end if
end sub
```

This code first a new para above second para and inserts Hello World in newly created second para.
Cheers....